# Syntax error trying to rename files

Tags: python, rename, python-os

```
import os


def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"file directory")
    print(file_list)
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(
            file_name,
            file_name.translate(str.maketrans("","", "0123456789")
       )

rename_files()
```

I keep getting a `syntax error` at the last line of the code. It doesn't give me any details, I just get a popup saying "invalid syntax" and it highlights the `rename_files` in red.
I tried running it without the line and it throws the same error. A little new to coding so be gentle haha.

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: Indent the long line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"file directory")
    print(file_list)
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(str.maketrans("","", "0123456789")))
rename_files()
```

try this